# Why does pdfcomment gobble space between words?

Tags: spacing, pdfcomment

With the following the space between "one" and "two" is gobbled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
  one \pdfcomment{comment}two
\end{document}
```

Why is that? Is it a bug or have I misunderstood the usage?

Comment: Switch the position of the spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a deliberate decision: there is an `\unskip` in the code which is active unless you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version = 1]{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
  one \pdfcomment{comment}two
\end{document}
```

With no option or `version = 2` (*i.e.* the current code), the package author has defined the semantics here to be that the comment should directly attach to the preceding text.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is the correct answer. (Pack­age doc­u­men­ta­tion, 1.1.4)